# WPF application Upgrade

Tags: wpf, installshield

I have,lets say, an application installed with version 1.00. Now I have an updated my application without any change to database. How should I upgrade my application to the new version without losing my data from previous version. I am creating setup file using InstalSjield in VS2013.

Comment: There are lots of articles/tutorials on this.  It is a broad question.  Google it and read.

Answer (score 0):

As a general answer, it depends on what kind of update you're doing. Read up on versioning, [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jjameson/archive/2009/04/03/best-practices-for-net-assembly-versioning.aspx) is a useful link. Also, remember to change the Upgrade Code in InstallShield.  You need to also read on the versioning process in InstallShield so you know what is actually happening and how to recover from any mistake you might make.  InstallShield will have it's own version number for the installer too.

Typically, anything that has changed since the last release should have an updated version.  If you have:

```
Assembly A (1.0.0.0)
Assembly B (1.0.0.0)
Assembly C (1.0.0.0)
InstallShield Project (version 1.0.0.0, Upgrade Code: ABCD-EF12-3456-7891)
```

and you make changes only to `Assembly A`, you should have

```
Assembly A (1.0.1.0)
Assembly B (1.0.0.0)
Assembly C (1.0.0.0)
InstallShield Project (version 1.0.1.0, Upgrade Code: 3456-7891-ABCD-EF12)
```